# how to get session id from curl and reuse it again for next GET request

Tags: python, curl

Im doing this curl request to get some data in python , how can i get session id of curl request so that i can reuse again.

```
commands.getoutput("curl -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" -k -u username:password -X GET https://10.39.11.4/wapi/v2.7/member -s"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

curl has a built-in cookie jar meant for storing just the cookies and sending them back to the server.

To store cookies in the cookie jar we use the -c flag and give it the name of a file we wish to store the cookies in.

```
$ curl -X POST -c cookies.txt -u "user1:password1" website.com/login
$ cat cookies.txt

# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_quiet-waters-1228.herokuapp.com FALSE / FALSE 0 _curl_test_app_rails_

session cm53d2RJN1VncV........
```

There you can find session ID .

**As Mentioned by *Daniel Stenberg*** (founder of cURL):

use -b cookies.txt in the subsequent curl command line to make use of those cookies

Comment: then use `-b cookies.txt` in the subsequent curl command line to make use of those cookies in the following transfer

Comment: Excellent explanation. Was looking for this all around. I was able to make request through postman for triggering a jenkins job but curl was not working. Thanks to you now its working!

Comment: also use --data with credentials in json format if required by the site's login API call.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the requests library, it has a Session management described here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

```py
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('username', 'password')
s.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
r = s.get('https://10.39.11.4/wapi/v2.7/member')
```

If you want to save a session and then load it, you should use [dict_from_cookiejar](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar) and [cookiejar_from_dict](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.cookies.cookiejar_from_dict) like this:

```py
# Save session
s_dict = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(s.cookies)
# Load session
cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(s_dict)
s = requests.session(cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: i need the session id of the curl command,  how to get session id ,so that next it should not open new session

Comment: @user9056715 if you want to save a session and use it later, check out the updated answer. You could also pickle the resulting object and save it to the file